# order_by() doesn't work with filter() in Django view

Tags: django

My model:

```
...
class Bild(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    slot = models.IntegerField()
    bild = models.ImageField(upload_to='bilder', null=True)
    untertitel = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
```

My view:

```
def album_bild(request, album_id, bild_id):
    album_id = int(album_id)
    bilder = Bild.objects.filter(album__id = album_id).order_by('slot')
    ....
```

When I iterate through "bilder" in the template, I can see that the filter() did work but the objects are still ordered by the pk instead of the "slot".

Is there a problem with my usage of filter() and order_by()?

EDIT: I guess i should add that everything works fine in the shell. So maybe the error is in the template...?

```
{% for bild in bilder %}
    <li 
    {% ifequal bild.slot bild_id %}
            class="active" 
    {% endifequal %}
    onclick="window.location.href='/portfolio/{{ album_id }}/{{ bild.slot }}'"><div>{{ bild.slot }}</div></li>
{% endfor %}

{% for i in empties %}
    <li class="empty"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're not doing something like bilder.order_by(...) somewhere later in your view, are you?

Comment: Are you doing anything to bilder before you send it to the template?

Comment: I am doing the same type of filter and order_by in a project right now and the syntax is the same as what I have, but mine works... I'll be playing i the shell for a bit and trying to figure this out

Comment: The only thing I do later in the view involving bilder is this:     empties = range(18 - len(bilder))

Comment: For anyone using Django-Cryptography and stumbling on this post, ordering doesn't work either. I had to solve it by doing `sorted(Bild.objects.filter(album__id=album_id), key=lambda x: x.slot)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've done lots of `.filter().order_by()` chains just as you have them there, and nothing jumps out to me as out of place.  I've never tried to carry that ordering over to the template without further processing the objects though (usually iterate over them), so I wonder if the `order_by()` is lost as part of django's lazy evaluation?  Maybe try wrapping the `filter().order_by()` line in a `list()` to force evaluation there instead of it being put off till some later time?

```
bilder = list(Bild.objects.filter(album__id = album_id).order_by('slot'))
```

It is a shot in the dark, but quick enough to be worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Sadly that wasn't it. I think will avoid the problem by not giving all of the data to the template. In my case that might be inefficient anyway. But i'm still curious...

Comment: Oh, sorry. It actually worked! Thank you indeed! Using list() did the trick! (Although I still don't understand why...)

Answer (score 5):

You should try to order by slot__id.

Like this:

```
bilder = Bild.objects.filter(album__id = album_id).order_by('slot__id')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **views.py**
You need not use

```
filter(album__id = album_id)
```

(with double underscores)
since 'Album' is not related as a ManyToManyField

here 'Album' is just a ForeignKey

so the **views.py** should have

```
def album_bild(request, album_id, bild_id):
    album_id_local = int(album_id)
    bilder = Bild.objects.filter(album_id=album_id_local).order_by('slot')
    ....
```

(with a single underscore).

reference to django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 0):

If you too are using Django Rest Framework, I ended up here searching for why .order_by() was not working when applied to a queryset in my ModelView regardless of .filter() being present or not.

If you don't need to define your own get_queryset, don't! The django-filters library solved this issue for me replacing my conditional get_queryset function into 3 lines just using the OrderFilter.

[Original answer that helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56877581/6317921)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

xyz = Post.objects.filter(do something ).order_by('-slot')

Comment: Every other answer includes this piece of code in some form, please [edit] your answer to include information on why this solution works better compared to the other well-received answers.