# django rest framework queryset doesn't order

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i use model with `Meta` `ordering = ['-published_date']`

Now in view:

```
class InvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer
    filter_fields = ('table',)
```

And serializer:

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True, allow_add_remove=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('id',  'items', 'table', 'published_date')
```

But this ordering doesn't work, it shows me ordering ASC, and i need DESC, it doesn't affect order at all.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: if your call `Invoice.objects.all()` from the shell does it show DESC ordering?

Comment: Yes it does.. that's weird. :/

Comment: it must be somthing with DRF. what does your output look like?

Comment: I used rest client to see output, it just order it ASC. Can something be wrong with view, or serializer? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: you can override the `get_queryset()` method but, ive done this before  just like you and its worked for me. Somehting else must be wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Solution is to override `filter_queryset`:

```
def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
    queryset = super(InvoiceViewSet, self).filter_queryset(queryset)
    return queryset.order_by('-published_date')
```

Comment: That's a lot of overhead for a simple feature. I wonder if this has changed in the last 4.5 years?

Answer (score 32):

If your model does have an ordering it *really* will be reflected in the list view by default. I'd suggest overriding `get_queryset()` and debugging the return result there, or else explicitly adding the ordering to the queryset.

For example:

```
queryset = Invoice.objects.all().order_by('-published_date')
```

Wondering if it's possible you've configured a filter that's overriding the ordering.  Worth testing what happens if you turn all filters off.  I see you have the `filter_fields` attribute set, so assuming you've got something like this in your settings...

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

If you comment that out does that fix things?

Comment: It works when i comment this. Thanks, now can i make it work together?

Comment: The easy fix *should* be the `.order_by` listed above, but next step - why does using `DjangoFilterBackend` set an explicit ordering, instead of leaving the default? Is that a bug in `django-filter` or an integration issue in `REST framework`?

Comment: It still doesn't work when use `queryset = Invoice.objects.all().order_by('-published_date')` :(

Comment: Okay interesting, assuming that `django-filter` overrides the ordering then. Ticket is https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1717

Answer (score 30):

For Django REST Framework you can use [OrderingFilter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter).

```
from django_filters import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters


class InvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter)

    # Explicitly specify which fields the API may be ordered against
    ordering_fields = ('items', 'table', 'published_date')

    # This will be used as the default ordering
    ordering = ('-published_date')
```

Comment: For anyone thats banging their head on ordering via a query param manually in DRF, this solved a couple hour headache in minutes.Thank you!

Comment: If anyone's using django-filters and can't use another backend. See my answer below.

Comment: this explanation is pretty useful. Worth to mention that the import of `filters.OrderingFilter` **must** be from `rest_framework` instead of `django_filters`. This will may help to reduce hours of unnecessary headache, like the ones that I had

Answer (score 7):

@Mirza Delic answer works but does not keep the ordering comming from request.QUERY_PARAMS.

```python
class YOUR_VIEW_SET(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    #your code here
    ordering_filter = OrderingFilter()

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super(YOUR_VIEW_SET, self).filter_queryset(queryset)
        return self.ordering_filter.filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
```

This works for me and for other people I hope.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's coming here from google for 'How to order django-filters queryset'.

There's [OrderingFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#orderingfilter) in django-filters, which you can use to add the order_by functionality.
The example code from the docs looks like this :

```
class UserFilter(FilterSet):
account = CharFilter(field_name='username')
status = NumberFilter(field_name='status')

o = OrderingFilter(
    # tuple-mapping retains order
    fields=(
        ('username', 'account'),
        ('first_name', 'first_name'),
        ('last_name', 'last_name'),
    ),

    # labels do not need to retain order
    field_labels={
        'username': 'User account',
    }
)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

Where o is the name of the query param.
So if you hit `www.domain.com/o=username`. It will return the queryset ordered by username. If you want to order_by in descending order. Just do `www.domain.com/o=-username` (notice the - before username).