# OrderingFilter has no attribute 'filter_queryset'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to get [OrderingFilter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter) to work. From the example in django-rest-framework's page, it seems it should be fairly straightforward:

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('username', 'email')
```

However, when I try to do that:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend, FilterSet, OrderingFilter
...


class ListingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Listing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListingSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = ListFilter
    ordering_fields = ('price', 'views')
    ordering = ('price',)
```

I get an error about `OrderingFilter` not having a `filter_queryset` attribute:

```
ERROR 2016-11-13 03:14:57,304 log 25913 123145338523648 (<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'OrderingFilter' object has no attribute 'filter_queryset'",), <traceback object at 0x106ef48c8>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 474, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 40, in list
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 151, in filter_queryset
    queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
AttributeError: 'OrderingFilter' object has no attribute 'filter_queryset'
```

Going into `OrderingFilter`, it indeed does not have a `filter_queryset` method, but the view expects it:

```
# in GenericAPIView(views.APIView)
def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
    """
    Given a queryset, filter it with whichever filter backend is in use.

    You are unlikely to want to override this method, although you may need
    to call it either from a list view, or from a custom `get_object`
    method if you want to apply the configured filtering backend to the
    default queryset.
    """
    for backend in list(self.filter_backends):
        queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
    return queryset
```

I have tried the various solutions in [django rest framework queryset doesn't order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987446/django-rest-framework-queryset-doesnt-order), but it seems they do not work, either. I tried updating the most promising answer:

```
class YOUR_VIEW_SET(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    #your code here
    ordering_filter = OrderingFilter()

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super(YOUR_VIEW_SET, self).filter_queryset(queryset)
        return self.ordering_filter.filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
```

Since `OrderingFilter` does not have a `filter_queryset` method, I changed `filter_queryset` to `filter` (which it does have), but this call seems to clash with the signature of `filter` in `OrderingFilter`:

```
# In OrderingFilter(BaseCSVFilter, ChoiceFilter)
def filter(self, qs, value):
    if value in EMPTY_VALUES:
        return qs

    ordering = [self.get_ordering_value(param) for param in value]
    return qs.order_by(*ordering)
```

I have no idea what `value` in the function declaration is supposed to be so I could try to pass it to the function, but it seems `qs` refers to the queryset, so I assume that should be the first argument instead of the second, but again, I am not entirely sure what `value` would be; it doesn't seem to be request because it is not iterable.

I would appreciate any pointers or ideas, or workarounds, and I apologize if I missed something obvious; I am not terribly familiar with Django.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Just ran into this myself!

Don't use the class from django_filters, use  `rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter` instead.

```
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend, FilterSet
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I can't help but feel it is fairly confusing that there are several `OrderingFilter` classes all spread in different places, though.

Comment: I totally agree. Not sure what the other one is for, hopefully it's useful to someone

Comment: This saved me a ton of time!  Can't believe it's not a more common issue than these votes/views indicate.  Thanks!

Comment: God, I hate how many classes within DRF/Django share the exact same names, you've saved me time, thank you!

Comment: NOTE: This import is NOT from `django_filters.rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter`. This is also a valid import path with an OrderingFilter, but it is the incorrect one. This is from the `rest_framework` package itself.