# order_by did't work after filtering by foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s"%self.title

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    idlink = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    posted = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s"%self.title
```

And my views.py is

```
def list_video_cat(request, slug):
    video = Video.objects.filter(category__slug=slug).order_by('-posted')
    return  render(request, 'category.html', {'videos':video})
```

I want to show my post new to old, but it seems to did not work at this situation. What should I do?

**P/S the "duplicated post" does not solve my problem**

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625842/order-by-didt-work-after-filtering-by-foreign-key

Comment: possible duplicate of [order\_by() doesn't work with filter() in Django view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114718/order-by-doesnt-work-with-filter-in-django-view)

Comment: @maazza I read it, but the answer did not work for me

Comment: How did you find that it's not working? In your template rendering? Have you tried to put a break point just before your return and examine the queryset? Have you tried to remove the filtering to see if just doing the `order_by` would work?

Comment: @ShangWang in my template, I just use  {% for video in videos %} to render it. I tried order_by without filter, but the filter is the condition I need

Comment: @ShangWang please tell me what should I do, I am waiting the answer since I posted this question!!!

Comment: I know you need the filter, but my question is, if you just try your query without the filter in django shell, does it give you the right order?

Comment: @ShangWang I have just tried it, it does not work correctly what I want. I am thinking that this is Django's problem

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe it is. I assume that you really tried what the other user suggested(using a list to enforce the queryset to expand). If you really want to make it work, use python sort
`videos = sorted(videos, key=lambda video: video.posted, reverse=True)`

Comment: @ShangWang I think my problem is I order_by by "posted" method which is "DateField", so Django can't understand it. I change it to "id" and it works like what I want. I dont understand why Django does not understand it. But thanks for all your helps